# Change password reset redirect link in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, passwords

I am following [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) tutorial on setting up authentication with Laravel and I am mostly there apart from one bit.

When I make a request for a password reset I get an email sent out to me and if I click on the link in the email I get to a form which I then fill in correctly and expect to be redirected back to /dashboard, however this never happens and instead it redirects to /home.

I can't provide any code as everything is done behind the scenes by Laravel. Any help appreciated : ).

Comment: Let me consult my crystal ball... Nope, nothing. How about you post some code so I don't have to try divining it?

Comment: I am not sure what code to post as pretty much all of the work is done behind the scene by Laravel

Comment: You're going to have to do some work to narrow down the issue then aren't you? There's no way we can know what your code is doing to cause this. If I install a fresh copy of Laravel it will work fine. Start there (with a fresh copy) and start making changes, test it at each stage until it finally stops working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you are expecting the reset password controller to redirect you to `/dashboard` on a successful reset. Maybe I'm wrong, but I can't see anywhere in the code where that is specified (based, as you say, on a fresh Laravel install).

To demonstrate this, let's follow the code:

By default in a fresh Laravel installation you get a `PasswordController` in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/` directory. On [line 21 of that file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php#L21), it 'includes' the `ResetsPasswords` trait. So let's look at that trait.

As you can see, in the `postReset` method (which is the method that is run to do the final actual password reset), on [line 95](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L95) the redirect location is deferred to `redirectPath`, and as you can see, on [line 131](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L131) the code specifically forwards the user to `/home` if no `redirectPath` or `redirectTo` property exists on the controller.

So, to manually set the redirect location, just set `protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';` in your `Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController` class.

But also, on the page you linked to, see the section ["After resetting passwords"](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#after-resetting-passwords) for the official docs on this.

Comment: I don't know how I missed the section specifically on "after resetting passwords" in the docs, but this was extremely helpful for me. I had already changed the `$redirectPath` in the AuthController and assumed that would cover everything authentication related, but obviously not. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For Laravel 5.3 you have to set a property `redirectPath` in your `PasswordController` which is used for redirection after the login when you are using the built-in function by Laravel.

Should look like this:

```
# PasswordController.php

protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

**Since Laravel 5.4 the property was renamed to `$redirectTo`:**

```
# PasswordController.php

protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

Comment: In 5.4 I believe this has changed to: `protected $redirectTo = '/';` you can also read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart under *Path customization*

Answer (score 3):

If someone need different address when redirect (based on e.g user role) can add this to ResetPasswordController

```
public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (auth()->user()->hasRole(xyz)) {
            return route('');
        }

        return route('');
    }
```

Comment: i just learned something today. thank you! `[+1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spark, you will need to override `getResetSuccessResponse()` in `/spark/src/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php`.

Why?

Because `/spark/src/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php` uses the `ResetsPasswords trait` which has the `getResetSuccessResponse()` and it redirects to the `redirectPath()` which comes from the `RedirectsUsers trait` which is part of the Laravel framework that can't be changed.

Somehow this is ignoring the `$redirectTo` property and sending the user to `/home` instead of what's been declared in `$redirectTo`:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
  if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
    return $this->redirectPath;
  }

  return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

Or maybe just create the `$redirectPath` property somewhere.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.6 `$redirectPath` is not a valid attribute. Use `$redirectTo` instead.

See: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#after-resetting-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of field `redirectTo` of `Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController`:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

if you want to use a dynamic route, valorize that field from the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->redirectTo=route('home');
}
```